# Flutter web - inconsistent colours after build

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Good day.
I am in the process of deploying a flutter web app to production - all is well except the colours are inconsistent after the build - on chrome mobile (and Firefox) the colours appear pale  - even white text appears with a shade of blue.

Here's how I have defined the colors in question:

```
ThemeData(
primaryColorLight: Color(0xFF2346DF),
primaryColor: Color(0xFF3B3FC3),
primaryColorDark: Color(0xFF3B3FC3),
```

)

I have tried to build using both the html and CanvasKit renderer individually, no distinction in the problem.
I also tried to define the theme values using the provided `Color()` constants (e.g `Colors.blue`), no difference.

Any sort of explanation as to why this is happening will be highly appreciated - thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, could you provide more context on specific element that are changed and code ? I have a web project and all colors are working fine on mobile, firefox and chrome

Comment: @Wapazz Thank you for your comment - it prompted me to do a little more 'troubleshooting' - I still haven't realised the cause of the behaviour, but it seems the problem is only present when I use the provided `ThemeData()` class. - if you define a `primaryColor` in `MaterialApp` and then call `Theme.of(context).primaryColor` elsewhere, it's returning the default value not the one defined. Defining a constant (or using a separate class) and using it instead seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi! Did you add specified theme to `MaterialApp `? Like this: `MaterialApp(theme: yourThemeData, ...)`

Comment: @Mol0ko Yes, as mentioned above. And it worked just fine in the dev env (chrome). Only failed when I build the project.